# Set values of a dataframe based on a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to mask a Pandas dataframe based on booleans in another dataframe.

So, I've created a pandas DataFrame of `1` and `0`:

```
boolean_data = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
df_criteria = DataFrame(data=boolean_data, index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])
```

```
    x    y
A   1    0
B   0    1
C   0    0
```

I would like to use the above `df_criteria` to mask values of a second dataframe `df_result`, i.e., where `df_criteria(i,j)=1`, `df_result(i,j)=0`.

```
df_result = DataFrame(
    data=[(10, 20), (30, 20), (10, 10)],
    index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])
```

`df_result` (before masking)

```
   x    y
A  10   20
B  30   20
C  10   10
```

`df_result` (after masking)

```
   x    y
A  0   20
B  30   0
C  10  10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, Using `mask`

```
df_result.mask(df_criteria==1,0)
Out[55]: 
    x   y
A   0  20
B  30   0
C  10  10
```

Comment: You could use `inplace=True` if you wanted `df_result` to be changed directly instead of a new dataframe being returned.

Comment: Equivalently, `df.mask(df_criteria.astype(bool), 0)`, just to emphasize the criteria is a Boolean dataframe / array.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.DataFrame.iloc` and `numpy.where`:

```
df.iloc[:] = np.where(df_criteria, 0, df)

print(df)

    x   y
A   0  20
B  30   0
C  10  10
```